# logon process process name RASMAN

Tags: windows-server-2003, login

today when i check my event log on windows 2003 server i found this event

i am not sure what is this

[image]

can you explain what is this event for ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RASMAN is for Remote Access Service Manager, I think, it's someone who use your server to authenticate a remote session authentication (like remote connection before login on windows xp).

Hope it helps.